# How to make HAML output HTML as HTML, not encoded text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Most of my HAML works just fine, but the following line...

```
%td= user.roles.map { |r| link_to(r.name, r)}.join(', ')
```

...returns...

```
<td>
  &lt;a href=&quot;/roles/1&quot;&gt;admin&lt;/a&gt;
</td>
```

...when naturally I want it to return...

```
<td>
  <a href='/roles/1'>
    admin
  </a>
</td>
```

The following does not fix the situation:

```
%td= user.roles.map { |r| link_to(r.name, r).html_safe}.join(', ')
```

What should I do?

Steven.

Comment: Have you tried the `html_safe` after the join instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%td= user.roles.map { |r| link_to(r.name, r)}.join(', ').html_safe
```

Be careful about having all this logic in the view, though. You can accomplish a similar goal either by rendering a partial for each item in a collection, or by creating a helper method for you. It would read much cleaner as:

```
%td= role_links_for_user
```

or

```
= render user.roles
```